# Что за зверь - Allocator?

Tags: c++

Прошу, помогите с пониманием аллокаторов в c++.

Заметил, что `vector` можно создавать, используя некий "аллокатор". Задался вопросом, пошёл в интернет. Но по запросам, которые, казалось бы, должны давать ответ, я получил лишь сухие статьи, а стаковерфлоу показывает мне вопросы типа "как написать аллокатор" и т.д.

Все, что я понял - это то, что аллокатор используется для управления памятью. Можно написать свой, который будет управлять ей как-то по-умному.

А в чем тогда суть? Что, я могу, к примеру, написать аллокатор, который будет выделять память не последовательно, а кусочками в разных уголках памяти?
И если я создам вектор с таким аллокатором, то почему в справке по контейнеру `vector` написано, что, мол, он хранит все данные последовательно и непрерывно в памяти? 
Или я чего-то не понимаю? 
Единственное, что я, кажется, понял - так это то, что стандартный аллокатор выделяет память через оператор `new`, используя стандартный конструктор, что "не особо эффективно, учитывая, что не всегда нужно инициализировать все объекты, под которые мы выделяем место".

Так для чего же на самом деле нужны аллокаторы? Можно объяснить как-то кратко и на пальцах, почему и зачем?

Comment: `allocator`, это некий метод который будет выделять память под объект. Это может быть `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` или оператор `new` На этом все. Так же стоит отметить, что по тому как вы написали `все данные последовательно и непрерывно в памяти`, потому что при ресайзе, выделяется новый участок памяти, старый освобождается, там самым все данные будут идти последовательно, а не отрывками, или же указателями на отрывки данных в куче.

Comment: Эта тема достаточно темная :), крайне редко используемая - только в очень специфичных случаях (типа попыток повысить скорость путем применения своего аллокатора), так что обычно их мало кто использует - возни много, толку, как правило, мало.  Можете посмотреть о них немного в книге Джосаттиса *[Стандартная библиотека С++](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1837-6.html)*. И, само собой, когда вектор просит аллокатор выделить память для N элементов и вернуть указатель на нее - как вы себе представляете выделение **не** одним куском? :)

Comment: @Harry Я не особо всматривался в то, какие на нем функции можно вызывать, думал, что оно как-то запрашивает поэлементно. Это многое объясняет)

Comment: @Harry, тема тёмная, да, а вот все Ваши последующие утверждения не основаны ни на чём.

Comment: @ixSci Поэтому я и пишу комментарий, а не ответ :) Основываюсь в основном на прочитанном в разных книгах. Постараюсь исправить свой ответ на основе вашего комментария. Итак, *самописные аллокаторы широко используются в различных прикладных программах, пишутся очень легко (ну, если это, конечно, С++98, а не С++11, и если пишется нетривиальный аллокатор...). Читать о них нужно в других книгах, не трогая книгу Джосаттиса. А когда вектор запрашивает у аллокатора блок памяти, аллокатор может вернуть фрагментированные участки.* Так правильнее? :)

Comment: @Harry, я не про это, а про то, что _«крайне редко используемая - только в очень специфичных случаях»_ и _«так что обычно их мало кто использует - возни много, **толку, как правило, мало**»_. Это довольно сильные заявления, которые с реальностью соприкасаются лишь частично.

Comment: @Harry Что значит _фрагментированные участки_? И ещё - вы просто пишете утверждения, из-за которых  (не знаю, правильные они или нет) у меня ещё больше вопросов. Хотелось бы все же обоснованный ответ с каким-нибудь, хм, примером работы аллокатора...

Comment: @selya, аллокаторы сложная тема, которая в рамках одного ответа не описывается. Если конечно кто-то захочет их для Вас расписать, то рекомендую указать для какого стандарта Вы хотите видеть ответ т.к. они активно изменяются начиная с C++11, и, если память мне не изменяет, в каждом из новых стандартов были какие-то изменения.

Comment: @ixSci c++11, однако немного "истории" я бы тоже глянул. А не подскажете, в таком случае, какую-нибудь книгу, в которой можно что-то почерпнуть по этой теме? (Не обязательно на русском).

Comment: @Harry, указал отличную книгу. Правда, насколько я помню, в первом её издании про аллокаторы будет побольше, чем во втором. Плюс ко второму есть дополнительные материалы на сайте: http://www.cppstdlib.com. Смотрите «Supplementary chapter».